# Docker swarm refuses to create containers with published ports

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

i have a 2 noded swarm (both with docker 19.03.1) which i have troubles with - i constantly receive

`"Pool overlaps with other one on this address space" module=node/agent/taskmanager"`

message when creating a service with a published port.

The swarm was created vanilla:

```
manager@ docker swarm init
```

```
worker@ docker swarm join...
```

I created a overlay network

```
manager@ docker network create -d overlay ids-net --attachable
```

Creating a simple service on both nodes works:

```
manager@ docker service create --replicas 2 --network ids-net hashicorp/http-echo -text="hello world"
```

result:

```
image hashicorp/http-echo:latest could not be accessed on a registry to record
its digest. Each node will access hashicorp/http-echo:latest independently,
possibly leading to different nodes running different
versions of the image.

ksi39hzojsfjr4jyqck1p4rib
overall progress: 2 out of 2 tasks
1/2: running   [==================================================>]
2/2: running   [==================================================>]
verify: Service converged
```

Issueing the following results in an endless loop:

```
manager@ docker service create --replicas 2 --publish published=5678,target=5678 --network ids-net hashicorp/http-echo -text="hello world"
```

showing the following:

```
image hashicorp/http-echo:latest could not be accessed on a registry to record
its digest. Each node will access hashicorp/http-echo:latest independently,
possibly leading to different nodes running different
versions of the image.

bjjxxomsgvsoitf55l7vuuz74
overall progress: 0 out of 2 tasks
1/2: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space
2/2: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space
```

The syslog shows the following:

```
Aug 01 15:47:03 docker dockerd[1106]: time="2019-08-01T15:47:03.283849008+02:00" level=debug msg="state changed" module=node/agent/taskmanager node.id=50coluxfs0lnx1kf07mhckito service.id=d3rxusuxfk18tuvi24l198btp state.desired=READY state.transition="ACCEPTED->PREPARING" task.id=wmu9898y2yl01ga5v40xfojmi
Aug 01 15:47:03 docker dockerd[1106]: time="2019-08-01T15:47:03.283977128+02:00" level=debug msg="(*Agent).UpdateTaskStatus" module=node/agent node.id=50coluxfs0lnx                   1kf07mhckito task.id=wmu9898y2yl01ga5v40xfojmi
Aug 01 15:47:03 docker dockerd[1106]: time="2019-08-01T15:47:03.284226242+02:00" level=debug msg="task status reported" module=node/agent node.id=50coluxfs0lnx1kf07mhckito
Aug 01 15:47:03 docker dockerd[1106]: time="2019-08-01T15:47:03.284870334+02:00" level=debug msg="(*Agent).UpdateTaskStatus" module=node/agent node.id=50coluxfs0lnx                   1kf07mhckito task.id=o036l4zcbzvnccjsp44fygnfr
Aug 01 15:47:03 docker dockerd[1106]: time="2019-08-01T15:47:03.285156543+02:00" level=debug msg="Allocating IPv4 pools for network ingress (ozjtk12iougu8fqjliqspvxx2)"
Aug 01 15:47:03 docker dockerd[1106]: time="2019-08-01T15:47:03.285200492+02:00" level=debug msg="RequestPool(LocalDefault, 10.255.0.0/16, , map[], false)"
Aug 01 15:47:03 docker dockerd[1106]: time="2019-08-01T15:47:03.285228022+02:00" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="Pool overlaps with other one on this address space" module=node/agent/taskmanager node.id=50coluxfs0lnx1kf07mhckito service.id=d3rxusuxfk18tuvi24l198btp task.id=wmu9898y2yl01ga5v40xfojmi
Aug 01 15:47:03 docker dockerd[1106]: time="2019-08-01T15:47:03.285265876+02:00" level=debug msg="state changed" module=node/agent/taskmanager node.id=50coluxfs0lnx1kf07mhckito service.id=d3rxusuxfk18tuvi24l198btp state.desired=READY state.transition="PREPARING->REJECTED" task.id=wmu9898y2yl01ga5v40xfojmi
Aug 01 15:47:03 docker dockerd[1106]: time="2019-08-01T15:47:03.285236079+02:00" level=debug msg="task status reported" module=node/agent node.id=50coluxfs0lnx1kf07mhckito
Aug 01 15:47:03 docker dockerd[1106]: time="2019-08-01T15:47:03.285726857+02:00" level=debug msg="(*Agent).UpdateTaskStatus" module=node/agent node.id=50coluxfs0lnx                   1kf07mhckito task.id=wmu9898y2yl01ga5v40xfojmi
Aug 01 15:47:03 docker dockerd[1106]: time="2019-08-01T15:47:03.286082096+02:00" level=debug msg="task status reported" module=node/agent node.id=50coluxfs0lnx1kf07mhckito
Aug 01 15:47:03 docker dockerd[1106]: time="2019-08-01T15:47:03.286697616+02:00" level=debug msg="(*Agent).UpdateTaskStatus" module=node/agent node.id=50coluxfs0lnx                   1kf07mhckito task.id=wmu9898y2yl01ga5v40xfojmi
Aug 01 15:47:03 docker dockerd[1106]: time="2019-08-01T15:47:03.287043607+02:00" level=debug msg="task status reported" module=node/agent node.id=50coluxfs0lnx1kf07mhckito
Aug 01 15:47:03 docker dockerd[1106]: time="2019-08-01T15:47:03.316386815+02:00" level=debug msg="state for task wmu9898y2yl01ga5v40xfojmi updated to REJECTED" method="(*Dispatcher).processUpdates" module=dispatcher node.id=50coluxfs0lnx1kf07mhckito state.transition="ASSIGNED->REJECTED" task.id=wmu9898y2yl01ga5v40xfojmi
```

I think there is a problem with the overlay network. 
A `manager@ docker inspect <network id>` on the manager yields:

```
    {
        "Name": "ids-net",
        "Id": "jzvu45w1b247whq6qsx3v7fdy",
        "Created": "2019-07-31T10:10:38.436102588+02:00",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.1.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.1.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            ...
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4098"
        },
        "Labels": {},
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "22a3eb7a8eec",
                "IP": "192.168.100.92"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

On the worker node, the network isn't created. (Is that correct?)

Here is the output of `ip r` from both machines as per request by @BMitch :

```
manager@ ip r
default via 192.168.100.11 dev ens192 onlink
10.255.0.0/24 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 10.255.0.1
10.255.1.0/24 dev br-686969a42803 proto kernel scope link src 10.255.1.1
10.255.23.0/24 dev docker_gwbridge proto kernel scope link src 10.255.23.1
10.255.42.0/24 dev br-c03d759e1553 proto kernel scope link src 10.255.42.1
192.168.100.0/24 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.92
```

```
worker@ ip r
default via 192.168.100.11 dev eth0 onlink
10.254.0.0/24 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 10.254.0.1
10.255.3.0/24 dev docker_gwbridge proto kernel scope link src 10.255.3.1
10.255.4.0/24 dev br-88f241f38441 proto kernel scope link src 10.255.4.1
192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.106
```

here is the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` from `manager`:

```
manager@ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "registry-mirrors": ["https://repo.ids.net"],
  "default-address-pools": [
    {"base":"10.255.255.0/16","size":24}
  ]
}
```

the one for the `worker` looks different:

```
manager@ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "registry-mirrors": ["https://repo.ids.net"],
  "default-address-pools": [
    {"base":"10.254.255.0/16","size":24}
  ]
}
```

And here is the ingress-network config:

```
root@docker:/etc/nginx/conf.d# docker network inspect ozjtk12iougu
[
    {
        "Name": "ingress",
        "Id": "ozjtk12iougu8fqjliqspvxx2",
        "Created": "2019-07-31T07:36:57.368162913Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.255.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "10.255.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": true,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": null,
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4096"
        },
        "Labels": null
    }
]
```

I have purged both systems multiple times, as well as restarted both servers from the scratch.

Can anyone guide me, please?

Thanks
M

Comment: Please include the output of `ip r` in your question.

Comment: @BMitch - done so

Comment: @BMitch - thanks for your assistance - i added the `daemon.json` files

Answer (score 1):

With the published port, docker is attempting to configure the ingress network:

```
Aug 01 15:47:03 docker dockerd[1106]: time="2019-08-01T15:47:03.285156543+02:00" level=debug msg="Allocating IPv4 pools for network ingress (ozjtk12iougu8fqjliqspvxx2)"
Aug 01 15:47:03 docker dockerd[1106]: time="2019-08-01T15:47:03.285200492+02:00" level=debug msg="RequestPool(LocalDefault, 10.255.0.0/16, , map[], false)"
```

That appears to be an entire `/16` for the ingress subnet, and overlapping with other subnets that docker has already allocated within that `/16` block:

```
10.255.0.0/24 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 10.255.0.1
10.255.1.0/24 dev br-686969a42803 proto kernel scope link src 10.255.1.1
10.255.23.0/24 dev docker_gwbridge proto kernel scope link src 10.255.23.1
10.255.42.0/24 dev br-c03d759e1553 proto kernel scope link src 10.255.42.1
```

---

Best guess is that you have configured networks and default address pools in an incompatible way. This may have been done by manually creating the `ingress` network, and there may also be settings inside the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file causing these collision.

---

Edit: from your update, this guess appears correct. You have configured three different parts of docker to use the same address space, which will result in collisions. And one of those parts, the ingress network, is using the entire address space just for itself. You should configure bridge networks (with the default address pool in daemon.json), overlay networks (with the address pool option during `docker swarm init` that you are almost certainly passing), and on the ingress network (which you likely manually created), to each have a separate non-overlapping CIDR block.

Comment: Okay - thanks for the excellent explanation - my network skills are really crappy. I will try to get that fixed. I will remove the swarm and edit the `daemon.json` and recreate the swarm. Don't know, how to recreate the docker0-interface and the docker_gwbridge. Hopefully, this will happen automatically when restarting the service...?

Comment: Apparently, i am too dumb to fix this issue - i can't see, which one (bridge, overlay or ingress) i have to change. If soneone is willing to guide me, i would be grateful..?